# Value of BP Contact email

Tags: email, contacts, sapb1

**EDIT** (OP comment copied here):

> *"I get an error message saying: Unable to cast COM object:"*

**Error**:

> No such interface supported - HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)

I'm having trouble with the core suite code to read the value of the email of a contact in BP.

The code for business partner email works:

```
string email = SwissAddonFramework.UI.Components.TextEdit.GetFromUID(pVal.Form, "60").Value;
```

but the code for contact email fails:

```
string email = SwissAddonFramework.UI.Components.TextEdit.GetFromUID(pVal.Form, "107").Value;
```

Does anyone know the correct format please? Thank you all

Comment: what do you mean with fail? what happens?

Comment: I get an error message saying: Unable to cast COM object - No such interface supported - HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE) (sorry, it won't let me post an image of the error here)